# CMake Error: could NOT find Python (missing: Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS NumPy) (found version "2.7.17")

Tags: python, cmake, python-3.7

I encounter with this error during my build

```
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS NumPy) (found
  version "2.7.17")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPython.cmake:556 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  faiss/python/CMakeLists.txt:116 (find_package)
```

I've already installed `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and also tried adding

```
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())")  \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")
```

Still get the same error. My python is in `/home/dfw/anaconda3/bin/python` and its version is 3.7.11. My cmake version is 3.21.1. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Cmake [finds](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) a python installed by `apt` in the `/usr` folder.  There are two ways to tell Cmake the special location of python :

- Set the [Python3_ROOT_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#hints) variable
- Set the [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable.

Defining the `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` and `PYTHON_LIBRARY` variables on the command line does not work because these variables are overridden when you call `find_package(python3)`.

Also when installing python-dev into the system you can explicitly specify that version 3 is required.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```